# Session logout at random intervals while using django in the project

Tags: django

While I am doing some operation in my project the session will be logged-out automatically in the middle. I have used Angular-6 as front-end, django as back-end technology.

In the `setting.py` I have changed all possible value for `SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT`:

```
SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 30 * 60
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Hi Thanh ..While using the application, in the middle the application logs out that means I need to re-login.       Thanks in advance.

Comment: We do not have ```SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT``` in Django (I have never met this before). You need ```SESSION_COOKIE_AGE``` (IMHO).

Comment: Hi Gachdavit ...Appreciate for that ,even I too set SESSION_COOKIE_AGE but still all of a sudden session logouts in the middle while I am using the application .Is there any other factor I need to consider ?